# Handling only images with thumbnail creator Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I created a simple Azure Function that creates thumbnails for images uploaded to a container on Azure which gets triggered by a `BlobTrigger`.

It's working fine but because my container has both image files as well as other types e.g. PDF, Excel, Word, etc., the function gets triggered by all these files.

I thought I could address this by making sure that we only process image files using the code below. It kind of works because it only processes image files but it still seems to create placeholder blobs for other file types in the target container.

For example, if it detects a file named `myfile.pdf` in the source container, it still creates a `myfile.pdf` in the target container but it's 0 Bytes.

How do I make sure that a non-image files completely get skipped and not even create placeholders in my target container?

```
[FunctionName("ImageResizer")]
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("my-source-container/{name}", Connection = "myconnection")] Stream input, string name, [Blob("my-thumbnails-container/{name}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "myconnection")] Stream outputBlob, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        var fileExtension = FileUtils.GetFileExtension(name);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileExtension))
        {
            if (fileExtension.ToLower() == "png" || fileExtension.ToLower() == "jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == "jpeg")
            {
                using (var image = Image.Load(input))
                {
                    image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(new ResizeOptions
                    {
                        Size = new Size(150, 150),
                        Mode = ResizeMode.Crop
                    }));

                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        if(fileExtension.ToLower() == "png")
                            await image.SaveAsPngAsync(outputBlob);
                        else if(fileExtension.ToLower() == "jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == "jpeg")
                            await image.SaveAsJpegAsync(outputBlob);
                    }
                }

                log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {input.Length} Bytes");
           }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         log.LogInformation(ex.Message, null);
     }
}
```

Comment: you can try to modify your trigger to only fire on images, such as `[BlobTrigger("my-source-container/{name}.png"` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#filter-on-file-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using declarative bindings using attributes this is unavoidable unless you can somehow filter out unwanted blobs using the `BlobTrigger` attribute. It's default behavior for an output binding to expect the binding to be necessary so it is created as soon as the Function is executed.

However, with .Net languages you can use runtime bindings so only blobs that are actually handled will lead to output files, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#binding-at-runtime). That way you have more control regarding when an output blob is created.

```cs
[FunctionName("ImageResizer")]
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("my-source-container/{name}", Connection = "myconnection")] Stream input, string name, IBinder binder, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        var fileExtension = FileUtils.GetFileExtension(name);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileExtension))
        {
            if (fileExtension.ToLower() == "png" || fileExtension.ToLower() == "jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == "jpeg")
            {
                using (var image = Image.Load(input))
                {
                    image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(new ResizeOptions
                    {
                        Size = new Size(150, 150),
                        Mode = ResizeMode.Crop
                    }));

                    var attribute = new BlobAttribute("my-thumbnails-container/{name}", FileAccess.Write); 
                    attribute.Connection = "myconnectionstring"; 
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) 
                    using (var stream = await binder.BindAsync<Stream>(attribute))
                    {
                        if (fileExtension.ToLower() == "png")
                            await image.SaveAsPngAsync(stream);
                        else if (fileExtension.ToLower() == "jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == "jpeg")
                            await image.SaveAsJpegAsync(stream);
                    }
                }

                log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {input.Length} Bytes");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.LogInformation(ex.Message, null);
    }
}
```

[Here](https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/dynamic-output-bindings-in-azure-functions/) is also a blogpost outlining what I just did.

Comment: Had to make a slight change to add connection string to the attribute but this works like a charm. I appreciate your help. I'm glad I learned about runtime binding. Thanks again!
Here's my final code:
`var attribute = new BlobAttribute("my-thumbnails-container/{name}", FileAccess.Write);
attribute.Connection = "myconnectionstring";
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var stream = await binder.BindAsync<Stream>(attribute))
{
   await image.SaveAsJpegAsync(stream);
}`

Comment: I do have one small complaint about this function though. The `BlobTrigger` doesn't seem to trigger right away. Both in my local testing as well as on Azure, I upload a blob through the portal into my source container. It's over a minute before the trigger invokes the function to create the thumbnail. Is this normal? I was expecting/hoping it to trigger the function within seconds of my uploading a file.

Comment: @Sam If you want faster response switch to an Event Grid triggered function, because the Blob Trigger relies on polling. See [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/5208#issuecomment-370583218) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python#polling)